# How to make proper animated graph in xmgrace?

Tags: linux, batch-file, animation, plot, xmgrace

I have a series of data files and I just simply want to show them in a movie file where for each data file color, legends will change. So I tried something like below:

```
for i in *dat; do gracebat $i -batch setup.batch -printfile fig-$i.png -hdevice PNG -hardcopy; done
```

after that I use usual `convert` command to make a movie out of the PNG files using:

```
convert -delay 50 fig-*.png animation.gif
```

This produces a movie like below:

[image]
Now I want to change the colour and as well as legend in each frame according to the data point. I know there needs to be changed something in the `setup.batch` file but I couldn't figure it out what should I write there? Can anyone please help me a bit?

The `setup.batch` file looks like:

```
TITLE "Energy barrier"
WORLD XMIN 0
WORLD XMAX 2
WORLD YMIN 0
WORLD YMAX 0.6
XAXIS TICK MAJOR 0.5
XAXIS TICK MINOR 0.25
YAXIS TICK MAJOR 0.1
YAXIS TICK MINOR 0.05
s0 LINE LINEWIDTH 2.0
```

It would be really helpful if someone has idea about keeping the plots in each frame instead of showing only one plot at a frame. As an example, now it shows only one line at each step but what would be the way If I keep the previous plots so then at the 8th frame I can shown all the 8 plots?

Comment: I know I have to change the setup.batch file in every step. So I tried the following but still doesn't work.
for i in *.dat; do gracebat $i -batch setup.batch$i -printfile fig-$i.png -hdevice PNG -hardcopy; done
Where for each batch file I have defined different color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make as many batch files as the number of data files. The following `bash` script will automatically generate batch files.

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f temp.batch
c=0;
for fullname in `find . -name "*.dat"`; do
  # Extract filename without extension
  fname=$(basename "$fullname")
  fname="${fname%.*}"

  # Keeping the plots in each frame
  echo READ BLOCK \"${fname}.dat\" >> temp.batch
  echo BLOCK xy \"1:2\" >> temp.batch
  echo s$c LINE LINEWIDTH 2.0 >> temp.batch
  echo s$c LINE COLOR $((c+1)) >> temp.batch          # change the colour
  echo >> temp.batch  # a blank line for readability

  cat temp.batch >> plot${fname}.batch

  # Set formatting and other global options
  echo WORLD XMIN 0 > plot${fname}.batch                # create or overwrite file
  echo WORLD XMAX 2 >> plot${fname}.batch
  echo WORLD YMIN 0 >> plot${fname}.batch
  echo WORLD YMAX 0.6 >> plot${fname}.batch
  echo XAXIS TICK MAJOR 0.5 >> plot${fname}.batch
  echo XAXIS TICK MINOR 0.25 >> plot${fname}.batch
  echo YAXIS TICK MAJOR 0.1 >> plot${fname}.batch
  echo YAXIS TICK MINOR 0.05 >> plot${fname}.batch
  echo PRINT TO \"${fname}.png\" >> plot${fname}.batch
  echo HARDCOPY DEVICE \"PNG\" >> plot${fname}.batch
  echo PRINT >> plot${fname}.batch
  ((c++));
done
rm -f temp.batch
```

Followed by calls to `gracebat` to create the `.png` image sequence.

```
for fullname in `find . -name "*.dat"`; do
  fname=$(basename "$fullname")
  fname="${fname%.*}"  
  gracebat -batch plot${fname}.batch -nosafe 
done
```

Then use the `convert` command to make the movie with a unique color for each data-set, keeping old plots in each new frame.

Ofcourse, if you just want to change the color and not keep the old plots, replace `temp.batch` with `plot${fname}.batch` in the `bash` script and get rid of the concatenation line.